# Extract all particular field from JSON in mule esb

Tags: json, groovy, mule, mule-studio, mvel

I have this json payload, I would want to collect all externalListingId in one shot -

```
{
"listings": {
    "numFound": 3,
    "listing": [
        {
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "pricePerTicket": {
                "amount": 100,
                "currency": "USD",
            },
            "paymentType": "1",
            "externalListingId": "12208278",
            "city": "New York"
        },
        {   "status": "ACTIVE",
            "pricePerTicket": {
                "amount": 4444,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "paymentType": "1",
            "externalListingId": "CID1421798897102:151681733",
            "city": "Seattle"
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am using MVEL expression -

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars['sData']]" source="#[(externalListingId in payload.listing)]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    </enricher>
```

But this is giving error !! - Message payload is of type: ReleasingInputStream.

Scenario - I would like to collect all externalListingId into flowVariable, convert to hashmap. I have another CSV file as input, would like to loop through that payload and check if this map contains the id!!

I am following this earlier post - 
[Extracting array from JSON in mule esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589428/extracting-array-from-json-in-mule-esb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transform the message's streaming payload to an object with:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
```

before the `enricher`, and remove the one you have inside of it.

You also need to fix your MEL, as the `listings` property is missing in it:

```
source="#[(externalListingId in payload.listings.listing)]"
```

Source: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing

Comment: After adding the json to object transformer before enricher, I am getting error - Message payload type LinkedHashMap, i guess I can no longer use MVEL expression to gather all externalListingId

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you to remove the transformer from within the `enricher`. And, no, you can totally use MEL to gather the value, that's the whole point of doing the JSON transformation. You actually have an issue in your MEL. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Great! got it working. In a expression filter I am checking #[flowVars['sData'].contains(payload.TicketID)]. I actually want if not contains then go-ahead condition

Answer (score 0):

it worked with the same definition.

`<flow name="test-mule-json-extractFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <enricher source="#[(externalListingId in payload.listings.listing)]" target="#[flowVars.ids]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        </enricher>
        <logger message=":::::::::::::::#[flowVars.ids]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>`

Note: the json input you mentioned is not valid due to available of an extra comma.

Comment: What is the message payload type after the `enricher`? Is it a `Map` or an `InputStream`? If a stream, then it's been consumed and is useless. In any case, it's clearer to have the transformation before the `enricher` to make clear what's the new payload type. In any case, I'm curious to know: what's the payload type after the `enricher`?

Comment: Hi David,the payload type after enricher was BufferInputStream.

Comment: Thanks Mohan. So it would be consumed by the transformer inside the `enricher` and thus rendered useless (using it will throw an exception). Thus I stay on my recommendation to place the transformer before the `enricher` so the payload becomes a `Map` and remains usable.