# Can not Extract json array properly in message Enricher mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I tried to extract json array data using message enricher. But in output I got some object data.How can I fetch properly?

Following is my flow

```
<flow name="readfileFlow1" doc:name="readfileFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="Test" moveToDirectory="Backup" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <enricher source="#[(name in payload.data)]" target="#[flowVars.myMap]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        </enricher>
        <logger message="#[payload.toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

When I print in logger then I got following output

```
INFO  2015-04-29 13:01:20,409 [[readfile].readfileFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream@15bc5cc
```

How can I extract properly all name 
I tried using for each . Using for each I can extract succesfully. But want to use message enricher. How can I do this using message enricher **MVEL**??

My json data is as follow..

```
{
   "data":[
       {
            "id" : "1",
    "name": "AAA"

        },
        {
            "id" : "5",
                "name": "DDD"
        },
        {
            "id" : "6",
                "name": "CCC"
        },


    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this..
silly mistake I made..
Following is my answer

```
<logger message="#[flowVars.myMap]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve to extract name and id from your JSON payload .. you will get it in logger

```
   <flow name="readfileFlow1" doc:name="readfileFlow1">
     <file:inbound-endpoint path="Test" moveToDirectory="Backup" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/> 
     <enricher source="#[message.payload]" target="#[flowVars.myMap]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
       <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
       <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
       <foreach collection="#[payload.data]">
       <logger level="INFO" message="Name :- #[payload.name] and Id:- #[payload.id]"/>
       </foreach>
       </processor-chain>
      </enricher>
     <logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars.myMap]"/>     
    </flow>
```

One more thing you JSON payload is not valid.. try to remove an extra `,` at the end .. so your valid JSON file will be :-

```
{
   "data":[
       {
            "id" : "1",
    "name": "AAA"

        },
        {
            "id" : "5",
                "name": "DDD"
        },
        {
            "id" : "6",
                "name": "CCC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rep. but I already did with for each.I want to do it with MVEL Message enricher

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question that you want to do it with MVEL .. no where you written in your requirement

Comment: Yes correct .. but you need to mention the approach you want to solve it .. People will be helping you in for each if you don't mention it clearly the approach you want to solve it :) anyways .. :)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589428/extracting-array-from-json-in-mule-esb   I guess you can get some help from here